# Multiplying values in a picklist, depending on the user's pick by another number obtained from another calculation

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist

I have 3 different values in my picklist. The API for said values are:
Category_A
Category_B
Category_C

And their respective numerical values are: 20,6, and 1.
If the user selects Category A, then I would like 20 to be multiplied by the number of days obtaining from EndDate__c - StartDate__c

If the user chooses B, then 6 needs to be multiplied by the number of days...
If the user chooses C, then 1 needs to be multiplied by the number of days...

This is my formula, but I don't know what I need to change in order to achieve what I want:

```
Case(Category__c,
"Category_A", 20,
"Category_B", 6,
"Category_C", 1,
NULL) * TEXT((EndDate__c - StartDate__c))
```

Comment: What result are you getting now? How is it incorrect from what you describe?

Comment: Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '*'. Expected Number, received Text.... And if I change Text to number I get --> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'NUMBER()'. Expected 0, received 1

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting two dates is already a number (number of days between the two). No additional functions should be necessary.

```
Case(Category__c,
"Category_A", 20,
"Category_B", 6,
"Category_C", 1,
NULL) * (EndDate__c - StartDate__c)
```

Comment: I tried this before, but I was getting this error: Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data type (Text)

Comment: @WatsonElementary You need to change your formula's return type to number.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @WatsonElementary You need to go back a screen. On the previous screen of the "create new field" wizard, there's an option to choose the return type, it should be set to Number instead of Text. Use the Previous button in the wizard instead of the browser's back button.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was that easy. Thanks again!

Comment: @WatsonElementary No problem, glad to help!